# Setting custom client id in AMP pages or how to override AMP Clinet_Id

Tags: html, analytics, amp-html, user-tracking

We have user session tracking in our html5 implemented web site where
We create cookies on client site and read them back on each page hit
to track the user session.

But in AMP pages, a page can be served from google amp cache which may not contains user detail and in response we get amp fallback client id.

So default ClientId will be different from our session id

**AMP ClientId:** 
amp-8hSrTtaBjbR7GoLJ74xZ2avEuf5o6ujo06ydVJXr9AxnbDVkEKaMA6SLE5Zqxmkt (64 bit)

**OUR ClientId (SessionId)** : 5774bcc7-bf36-428b-9b46-885f885efe3b (32 bit)

Is there any way in AMP to tell, in case of fallback ClientId using my custom implementation.

Need to implement this feature on our website.

Thanks in advance.

PS-If Anybody down vote the question please mention the reason in comment.It will help me to post relevant question.

Comment: is it related with GA (Google Analytics)

Comment: @BachchaSingh. This question is related with AMP page custom analytics.

Comment: try this : https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-analytics-client-id-amp-pages/